# Estate received unexpected IRS refund - bank account is closed

Tags: united-states, irs, estate

I was administratrix of my late sister's estate. Last November, everything had been finalized, the final check written to her surviving spouse, and I closed the estate bank account. This week I received in the mail a refund to the estate from the IRS. Frustrating because the estate paid exactly what we were instructed by the IRS to pay, and now there is this hiccup. What do I do with this check? I know the bank will not cash it. Can I just endorse it on behalf of the estate and forward it on to the spouse?

Comment: This is a good question, but might be better suited to Law.SE.